# how to populate android-viewFlow from SQLite database correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, populate

I'm trying to implement android-viewFlow (https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) in my app, however, I'm having hard time populating each page correctly.

The problem is that I have SQLite database, and I need to have a number of views that will match the number of rows matching my query (typically between 9 and 21), and each of those views should show values from that exact row.

In viewFlow, there's this "sidebuffer" field that will load the number of views depending on what's the value of this "sidebuffer". So, how do I populate the adapter from SQLite and force the "sidebuffer" to match my number of rows. (If "sidebuffer = 3", the views loaded will be 2 * 3 + 1, and if it's 5, then it will load 2 * 5 + 1).

Is there a downside of having "sidebuffer = 100" hard-coded even if I will never have even near that much of views to be shown?

The reason I'm using viewFlow, and not the Android's compatibility viewPager, is that I need the title indicator which is implemented.

Thanks in advance!

Right now, I've created a new method in viewFlow.java

```
public setSidebuffer(int sidebuffer) {
    mSideBuffer = sidebuffer;
    init();
}
```

and in my main_activity where I'm setting up the viewFlow I'm calling the method as follows:

```
viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
AndroidVersionAdapter adapter = new AndroidVersionAdapter(this);
viewFlow.setAdapter(adapter, 3);
viewFlow.setSidebuffer(adabter.getSize() / 2);    // THIS IS THE THING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that setting a sidebuffer greater than the number of elements in your adapter might cause a FC. In that case, there's a bug in android-viewflow I'll have to look into. Anyway, such large sidebuffer will cause your adapter to create a View for each and every element, thus consuming, potentially a lot, memory. The whole idea with the adapter is to only load Views when needed.

I think you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle when you're aiming on setting the complete buffer size to the size of your adapter. That's not how it is meant to be used. Implement your adapter in such way that when getView(...) is called, the adapter will retrieve the correct row from your database, inflate a view if necessary, and return the populated view. If this procedure is relatively fast you may stick with a low sidebuffer such as 2 or 3, because a user won't be able to scroll faster than it takes to load views into viewflow. Does that make sense?

If you rather like to use the ViewPager instead, you might want to have a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
This library is derived from work done in android-viewflow to enable indicators for ViewPager. Perhaps android-viewflow will support that as well in the future.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was just wondering why, if I had 10 rows for example to be shown and side buffer 3, the 8th view would somehow has a position of 0 and 9th has 1 etc.. so only fix to that i could come up was to load those all views all together.

Comment: and yes, after heavy googling I discovered that same Jake Wharton's library you suggested... and found it very good in fact. Although I have no idea how to get Eclipse accept it as external library. Won't even accept importing it/sample project... so I had to copy the files to my project folder

Comment: What index/position are you talking about? ViewFlow keeps track of two indexes. One for the position within the adapter and one for the index within the list of loaded views. The size of the list of loaded views is typically 2*sidebuffer + 1.

Comment: hi patrik, i was talking about the position in my adapter class. Just as in your example project, I have a static string array with 15 strings (in real app, this array should be populated from db)... and in getView method i'm inflating a view and trying to set text to match array index with the position (page currently showing) but all goes wrong when the page showing exceeds the sidebuffer. So, with sidebuffer value of 3, position gets values as follows: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1... so I'm never getting values from my array with idx greater than 6

Comment: So, your getView(...) in your adapter always gets a position between 0-6 even though there's more elements in the array? That seems very strange and nothing I cannot reproduce it. I tried with the Title example in viewflow and set the sidebuffer to 1. Still I get all the views when scrolling as expected. Please try the title example and lower the sidebuffer to 1 and see if what happens.